# Asking for help to uninstall Komorebi

Tags: uninstall, make

I am new here and not an English native, so excuse me for my language.

My problem is this: I have installed software from the source, without knowing how dangerous is it, and now I cannot uninstall it. I have to do what the software provider tells me to uninstall.

All the instructions are here: https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi

SO il follow this step :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vala-team -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging -y
sudo apt install cmake valac libgtk-3-dev libgee-0.8-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev libclutter-1.0-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev libclutter-gst-3.0-dev
git clone https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi.git
cd komorebi
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. && sudo make install && ./komorebi
```

So i try to uninstall be following this step :

If you manually installed Komorebi

Open Terminal

```
cd komorebi/build
sudo make uninstall
```

But in my terminal I have this answer :

`No rule to make the target 'uninstall'.` Stop
So I look on the web and someone tells i can uninstall by revering all the steps and knowing the step by this command :

```
make -n install
```

So I think I going to reverse all the steps but I just don't know how to do it, if someone can help me, please?

Another piece of Information, it become worst because I try to fix the problem by myself, ( because my graphic environment become unstable because of the software ), so I see on another forum people tell to directly delete the folders, so I try with the rm command and of course, it was a bad idea, so I launch a portable edition of Knoppix to get back the folders and it works, but two things appended, first the next command: `make -n install` don't give me result anymore and secondly I am not sure everything is back.

Thanks for reading.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

You can run these commands. It works for me and it took me 2 hours to find these commands.

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/komorebi.desktop
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/komorebi
sudo rm /usr/share/komorebi/komorebi.glade
sudo rm /usr/share/komorebi/komorebi.svg
sudo rm /usr/share/komorebi/pixmaps/*
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/komorebi.1.gz
sudo rm -rf /path/to/komorebi
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/komorebi
find ~/ -name "*komorebi*"
rm /path/to/komorebi/wallpapers/*
```

if the wallpaper creator still remains then you can navigate to "System/Applications" then open the terminal.

```
 sudo su
```

Run the command `ls`
you can see Komorebi.

Run the command with the name of the installed application.

```
rm -r installed_application_name
```

Then navigate to Resources folder and run the same command.

```
rm -r Komorebi
```

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled it by simply using Synaptic Package Manager, marking it for complete removal, applying then navigating as root to (File System)/System/Resources and deleting the Komorebi folder

Answer (score 0):

Make files can be a little hard to decipher but opening it in an editor will allow you to see where it was installed to. In there you will see the install section those are the commands and the paths the files were copied to. After you determine where they went remove them in terminal with the `rm /path/to/file/to/remove`  command.

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunately i do some error trying to fix my self ( i explain what in my first post ) and because of that i think i cannot anymore use your solution .

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are out of luck: When you manually build software, `sudo make install` is a one-way street: It installs files to the system, but there is no easy way to undo that. That's why package managers were invented (apt / dpkg in the case of Ubuntu).

However, this project uses *cmake* which does record what files were installed to the system in a file `build/install_manifest.txt`. You can use that to remove those files:

```
cd build
cat install_manifest.txt | sudo xargs rm
```

*Caveat*: Some directories might be left over. But that shouldn't hurt you.

I see that on their project home page, they claim that `sudo make uninstall` should work, but I don't see anything in their `CMakeLists.txt` file that would actually do that; and *cmake* does not do that by itself.

https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi#if-you-manually-installed-komorebi
https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering and helping . So i edite my post and explain my new complication and maybe because of that i cannot find the file : install_manifest.txt, should be in komorebi/build but he isn't . Also in my build folder i only have a file call CMakeCache.txt and another folder call CMakeFIles, in this last folder i have few files to, one is maybe helpful, call CMakeOutput.log .  If you need more information let me know , thanks again for your help .

Comment: Also i have maybe found two others solutions, the first is to create the file install_manifest.txt by install again the software in another session, and the second solution i found on the developers page but i am not sure what i have to do, did i have to delete the files or fist install something ? https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi/issues/232

Comment: That `build/install_manifest.txt` file is there after you did `sudo make install`.

Comment: Complete sequence: `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make; sudo make install` (as per the project's instructions) and THEN you have that file. Yes, it sounds a bit odd to repeat that `sudo make install`, but it will create that manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge komorebi
```

This **worked** for me.